# What are the contents of an Android APK file

Tags: android, apk

- what are the components of the APK file ?
- Is it just bunch of executable's ?
- what are the names of the components ?

Comment: Please use google for such kind of question. You can see which components are in an apk file and how it is built here: http://developer.android.com/tools/building/index.html

Answer (score 15):

An APK file is an archive that usually contains the following folders:

- **META-INF** directory:

  - MANIFEST.MF: the Manifest file
  - CERT.RSA: The certificate of the application.
  - CERT.SF: The list of resources and SHA-1 digest of the corresponding
    lines in the MANIFEST.MF file; for example:

    ```
     Signature-Version: 1.0 
     Created-By: 1.0 (Android)  SHA1-Digest-Manifest:
     wxqnEAI0UA5nO5QJ8CGMwjkGGWE=  
     ...  
     Name: res/layout/exchange_component_back_bottom.xml  SHA1-Digest:
     eACjMjESj7Zkf0cBFTZ0nqWrt7w=  
     ...  
     Name: res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png 
     SHA1-Digest: DGEqylP8W0n0iV/ZzBx3MW0WGCA=
    ```
- **lib**: the directory containing the compiled code that is specific to a
  software layer of a processor, the folder is split into more folders
  within it:

  - armeabi: compiled code for all ARM based processors only
  - armeabi-v7a: compiled code for all ARMv7 and above based processors
    only
  - x86: compiled code for x86 processors only
  - mips: compiled code for MIPS processors only
- **res**: the directory containing resources not compiled into
  resources.arsc .
- **assets**: a directory containing applications assets, which can be
  retrieved by AssetManager.
- **AndroidManifest.xml**: An additional Android manifest file, describing
  the name, version, access rights, referenced library files for the
  application. This file may be in Android binary XML that can be
  converted into human-readable plaintext XML with tools such as
  AXMLPrinter2, apktool, or Androguard.
- **classes.dex**: The classes compiled in the dex file format
  understandable by the Dalvik virtual machine

  **resources.arsc** : a file containing pre-compiled resources, such as
  binary XML for example.

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_%28file_format%29)

Comment: why there are two manifest files?, One is inside META-INF and other is AndroidManifest.xml @CRUSADER

Answer (score 12):

```
[APK] 
|
|_ _ _ _ DALVIK EXECUTABLE < This is a code that runs the android app >
|
|_ _ _ _ RESOURCES < Images, video files, Audio files, xml files, Language packs >
|
|_ _ _ _ NATIVE LIBRARIES < some native code that include c & c++ libraires >
```

Answer (score 6):

You can extract your apk to see whats inside it ,by just renaming it to "apkname.zip".

After renaming you can extract it like normal zip files.I guess this is what you wana see.

Comment: remove ".apk" and replace it with ".zip" .

Comment: You even do not need to rename it to ".zip". It is a normal archive extension and there are tools that can open it directly, like the archive manager of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

An apk file contains all of that program's code (such as .dex files), resources, assets, certificates, and manifest file.