# Fast way to get hash of .apk in my application?

Tags: android, hash, android-ndk, apk

I'm developing an application that computes hash of already installed applications. Currently my solution flow is

> open_apk -> put_content_into_buffer -> compute_hash and it takes 26s.

I was wondering if there is another way to retrieve hash in a faster way, maybe there is something already computed inside a **`.apk`** header?

Comment: What kind of hash? What are the requirements? How fast does it have to be?

Comment: The APK has the sha1 hash of every file. See [apk contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18717286/what-are-the-contents-of-an-android-apk-file)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I know that inside apk there is a list of all elements contained in apk and their sha1 but this information doesn't fit my needs... the point is that I need the sha1 of the whole apk content in order to have a  unique id for each application.